# How do I share Google Cloud Print printers with ALL users in a Google Apps domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-print

How do I share Google Cloud Print (GCP) printers with ALL users in a Google Apps domain? Sharing GCP printers with specific groups in an Apps domain would be even better. I can add groups to the allowed list in GCP, but when I try sharing a "Classic" printer with Group A and printing from a user in Group A, it doesn't even show the shared printer as a GCP printer in the GCP printer menu.

Further hindering Apps users is the lack of a universal policy or default for printing; all printers must have their permissions created **individually**, which is a huge headache for admins.

[This Google FAQ](http://support.google.com/cloudprint/?hl=en&expand=shareprinter#share) seems to imply that the owner of the group in question needs to authorize or accept access to the GCP printer, but doesn't specify how to do this in Google Apps.

Cross posted at https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/how-to/6ErOP2Xhu_s

Answer (score 4):

Turn on printer sharing through Chrome. In the manage printers click share. Enter the email address of the group.

Now go into your Google Apps domain settings. Assign an owner to the group.

Once you have done that, log into chrome with that group owner and navigate to [CloudPrint](http://www.google.com/cloudprint), and click on "Printers".

You should get a message asking if you want to accept, and if you want to accept for the whole group.